# Spring bean creation error

Tags: java, spring

So I've been following the Spring documentation, specifically this part,

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators on Dependency Injection, but whenever my code runs, I get an error about bean creation.

Here is portion of my code that I tried to base off the ExampleBean example,

```
public class TimeFeedHandler implements MessageListener {

    String msgID = null;

    TimeBayeuxService timeBayeuxService;

        public void setTimeBayeuxService(TimeBayeuxService timeBayeuxService) {
            this.timeBayeuxService = timeBayeuxService;
        }
```

And my Spring XML file looks like this,

```
<!-- A POJO that implements the JMS message listener -->

<bean id="timeFeedHandler" class="com.example.streaming.time.TimeFeedHandler" >
<property name="timeBayeuxService" ref="timeBayeuxService"> </property>
</bean>
```

The error I get is,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timeFeedHandler' defined in URL....
```

Any ideas why or what I'm doing wrong?

Edit, here is the TimeBayeuxService bean,

```
<!-- Time BayeuxServices -->

<bean id="timeBayeuxService" class="com.example.streaming.time.TimeBayeuxService" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="common.bayeux" /></constructor-arg>
    <property name="timeBean" ref="time.time" />
</bean>
```

Here is more of the error. The full error log from STS is wayyyyy too long. I feel like I'm not referencing the TimeBayeuxService bean properly but logically I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timeFeedHandler' defined in URL [file:/Users/nullpoint/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'timeBayeuxService' while setting bean property 'timeFeedHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timeBayeuxService' defined in URL [file:/Users/nullpoint/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.example.streaming.time.TimeBayeuxService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
```

Here is a portion of the TimeBayeuxService class

```
public class TimeBayeuxService {

private Bayeux bayeux;
private static StreamingTimeLogGatherer logGatherer;
String testMsgTS = "This is a test message from the original service";

public TimeBayeuxService(Bayeux bayeux) extends SomeBayeuxService{
    super(bayeux, TimeBayeuxService.class.getName());

    this.bayeux = bayeux;
    final Bayeux fbayeux = bayeux;

    this.logGatherer = logGatherer;
    LogServlet.addLogGatherer(logGatherer);

    startThread(fbayeux, testMsgTS, true);

}
```

Comment: TimeBayeuxService is one interface and you have one implementation of that?

Comment: Can you check if your package name is correct `com.example.streaming.time`? Also add the bean definition for `timeBayeuxService`. For proper coding sake- make `timeBayeuxService` private

Comment: Is that the only error message you're getting? It looks rather incomplete to me.

Comment: Yes I have an implementation of TimeBayeux.

The error message I cut out because it's really really long, let me edit it and I'll post it up in a bit

Comment: Added more of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeFeedHandler` has a dependency on `timeBayeuxService`. It can't initialize `timeBayeuxService` due to NullPointerException so spring can't inject the bean.

According to the error message the NullPointerException happened in the constructor of `com.example.streaming.time.TimeBayeuxService`. How are you creating `common.bayeux` bean? Please paste the constructor code for `TimeBayeuxService` class. Is it an interface? Then you should put the implementation class in the bean definition.

The possible places for NPE. Without the complete stack trace I have to guess the following lines of code:

1. It can happen inside the constructor of the super class.
2. These 2 methods:  `LogServlet.addLogGatherer(logGatherer); startThread(fbayeux, testMsgTS, true);`

Comment: Added code :)

Thanks so much for taking the time so far CoolBeans, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @soulesschild - There are number of places where the NPE could occur in your constructor. Do you see which line the NPE happend in the stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace shows,

`at com.example.streaming.common.SomeBayeuxService.<init>(SomeBayeuxService.java:33)
 at com.example.streaming.time.TimeBayeuxService.<init>(TimeBayeuxService.java:22)`

Line 22 is 

`super(bayeux, TimeBayeuxService.class.getName());`


I am trying to find the source code of SomeBayeuxService as it's something that gets pulled from Maven in a JAR

Comment: @soulesschild - is that the first line in the stack trace after the NullPointerException message? If so then you need to find out what is going on on SomeBayeuxService.java class line 33.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out CoolBeans, I will wade my way through the stack trace and classes to see if I can't fix it :) Have a few senior developers helping me out as well (I'm a developer in training :) )